# unable to validate table in controller of laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, validation

i have function in controller that repeatedly generates a table via ajax request

i want to validate table every time ajax makes request to this function

how can i validate the start date and law reg no of the table when ajax fetches it with click of button.

my code for function:

```
public  function postlawsdata()
    {
        $lawdata = Input::get('law_type_id');
        $sublawdata = Input::get('law_sub_type_id');
        $start_date = Input::get('start_date');
        $res_div = '';
        $sub_law_count = count($sublawdata);
        $validate_laws = '';
        if (count($sublawdata) > 0) {

            for ($i = 0; $i < count($lawdata); $i++) {
                $law_details = DB::table('tbl_law_master')->where('id', $lawdata[$i])->select('tbl_law_master.id as law_id', 'tbl_law_master.lm_id', 'tbl_law_master.law_name')->first();

                $sublaw_details = DB::table('tbl_law_sub_master')
                    ->where('tbl_law_sub_master.lm_id', $lawdata[$i])
                    ->whereNull('tbl_law_sub_master.deleted_at')
                    ->select('tbl_law_sub_master.id as sublaw_id', 'tbl_law_sub_master.sub_law_name', 'tbl_law_sub_master.lms_id')->get();


                if (count($sublaw_details) > 0) {
                    $res_div .= '<table width="100%" border="0"  class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">';
                    $res_div .= '<tr>
                                    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">    
                                        <strong>' . $law_details->lm_id . ' (' . $law_details->law_name . ')</strong>
                                    </td>   
                                    <td >
                                        <span class="required" aria-required="true">* </span><input type="text" value="' . $start_date . '" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY (Start Date)" name="law_start_date[]" id="law_start_date" att_law_id="' . $lawdata[$i] . '"  class="date-picker required locationformstyle locationparentsd dynamiclocationparentsd' . $lawdata[$i] . '">
</td></tr><tr><td>
                                        <span class="required" aria-required="true">* </span><input type="text" placeholder="Law Registration No." name="law_reg_no" id="law_reg_no" class="locationformstyle required">

                                    </td>
                                    </tr>';

                    foreach ($sublaw_details as $sublawdetails) {
                        if (in_array($sublawdetails->sublaw_id, $sublawdata)) {
                            $res_div .= '<tr>
            <td width="220">Start Date: <input type="text" name="sub_law_start_date[]" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" onfocus="this.blur()" class="locationformstyle date-picker dynamiclocationparentsd' . $lawdata[$i] . '" att_law_id="' . $lawdata[$i] . '"> </td>
            <td width="220">End Date: <input type="text"  name="sub_law_end_date[]" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" onfocus="this.blur()" class="locationformstyle date-picker"></td>
            <td align="left"><strong>' . $sublawdetails->lms_id . ' (' . $sublawdetails->sub_law_name . ')</strong>
            <input type="hidden" class="locationformstyle" name="company_sub_laws[]" value="' . $sublawdetails->sublaw_id . '">
            </td>
            </tr>
            ';
                        }
                    }
                    $res_div .= '</table>';
                }
            }
        } else {
            $validate_laws = 'Please Select Atleast One Law';
        }
        $data = array(
            'law_info' => $res_div,
            'validate_laws' => $validate_laws,
            'sub_law_count' => $sub_law_count
        );
        return json_encode($data);
    }
```

Comment: Check *Writing The Validation Logic* section from [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation)

Answer (score 2):

create a new validator like so;

```
public  function postlawsdata()
    {

     
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'start_date' => 'required',
        //add other fields here with custom validation rules
        ]);
     
        if ($validator->passes()) {

          $lawdata = Input::get('law_type_id');
        $sublawdata = Input::get('law_sub_type_id');
        $start_date = Input::get('start_date');
        $res_div = '';
        $sub_law_count = count($sublawdata);
        $validate_laws = '';
        if (count($sublawdata) > 0) {

            for ($i = 0; $i < count($lawdata); $i++) {
                $law_details = DB::table('tbl_law_master')->where('id', $lawdata[$i])->select('tbl_law_master.id as law_id', 'tbl_law_master.lm_id', 'tbl_law_master.law_name')->first();

                $sublaw_details = DB::table('tbl_law_sub_master')
                    ->where('tbl_law_sub_master.lm_id', $lawdata[$i])
                    ->whereNull('tbl_law_sub_master.deleted_at')
                    ->select('tbl_law_sub_master.id as sublaw_id', 'tbl_law_sub_master.sub_law_name', 'tbl_law_sub_master.lms_id')->get();


                if (count($sublaw_details) > 0) {
                    $res_div .= '<table width="100%" border="0"  class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">';
                    $res_div .= '<tr>
                                    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">    
                                        <strong>' . $law_details->lm_id . ' (' . $law_details->law_name . ')</strong>
                                    </td>   
                                    <td >
                                        <span class="required" aria-required="true">* </span><input type="text" value="' . $start_date . '" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY (Start Date)" name="law_start_date[]" id="law_start_date" att_law_id="' . $lawdata[$i] . '"  class="date-picker required locationformstyle locationparentsd dynamiclocationparentsd' . $lawdata[$i] . '">
</td></tr><tr><td>
                                        <span class="required" aria-required="true">* </span><input type="text" placeholder="Law Registration No." name="law_reg_no" id="law_reg_no" class="locationformstyle required">

                                    </td>
                                    </tr>';

                    foreach ($sublaw_details as $sublawdetails) {
                        if (in_array($sublawdetails->sublaw_id, $sublawdata)) {
                            $res_div .= '<tr>
            <td width="220">Start Date: <input type="text" name="sub_law_start_date[]" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" onfocus="this.blur()" class="locationformstyle date-picker dynamiclocationparentsd' . $lawdata[$i] . '" att_law_id="' . $lawdata[$i] . '"> </td>
            <td width="220">End Date: <input type="text"  name="sub_law_end_date[]" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" onfocus="this.blur()" class="locationformstyle date-picker"></td>
            <td align="left"><strong>' . $sublawdetails->lms_id . ' (' . $sublawdetails->sub_law_name . ')</strong>
            <input type="hidden" class="locationformstyle" name="company_sub_laws[]" value="' . $sublawdetails->sublaw_id . '">
            </td>
            </tr>
            ';
                        }
                    }
                    $res_div .= '</table>';
                }
            }
        } else {
            $validate_laws = 'Please Select Atleast One Law';
        }
        $data = array(
            'law_info' => $res_div,
            'validate_laws' => $validate_laws,
            'sub_law_count' => $sub_law_count
        );
        return json_encode($data);
     

        }
     
        return response()->json(['error'=>$validator->errors()->all()]);
    }
```

add `use Validator;` at the top.

Comment: replace $request with request()

Comment: bro when i submit my form i can't see my table

Comment: the data is not passing the validation then, check the validation rules.